# Remove function of R in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a situation, in this moment i have a lot of variables in my python environment, i want to to remove this variables with some function. I know that in `R` i use the function `rm()` to remove all variables i want. The question is, Is there such a variable like that  in python?.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Here i create a object, now i want remove it of the python environment, i have used `list.remove(df)`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the `del` function:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
>>> del df
>>> df
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer